# How to specify trigger key for content assit in Eclipse RCP editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

There is a method `getCompletionProposalAutoActivationCharacters` in `ContentAssistProcessor` that can return characters which trigger the completion proposals. For example I can `return new char[] { '.' }`  so that each time I type dot in the editor the word completion proposal shows up.

I thought that there should be a simular way to specify shortcut key stroke to trigger content assist such as `Alt + /`, but actually that's different.

What is the best way to do this? I personally don't want to hard code a key listener for this.

Comment: store the trigger char in plugin's preference for user ?

Comment: Yes, if it's applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDT does that. They have a command+handler+keybinding to invoke the content assist.
See [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaContentAssistHandler`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6.1/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.6.1/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/java/JavaContentAssistHandler.java#JavaContentAssistHandler) for the implementation.
You can do similar one